# KVC to add values from multiple Keys to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to display `name` and `lastName` in my `UITableViewCell`. I have an array with a lot of data that I retrieve from a database, and pretty much everything I need is in the array, the trick is to filter and show the results as I want.

I have the following code to filter what is being typed on `searchBar` and add to an `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"usuario.username contains [cd] %@", searchText];
NSArray *filtroUsuario = [name filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
searchResults = [filtroUsuario valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.usuario.nome"];
```

I use `@distinctUnionOfObjects` because the objects that I'm filtering are not `user` objects, therefore I want to retrieve `user` values, so as some objects point to the same `user`, I get duplicate `name`s.

The code to put information on the `UITableView` is like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = searchResults[indexPath.row];
```

It all works fine. My trouble is that now I want to show one more key on the cell, so the keypath would be `usuario.sobrenome`. How would I put both values together?

I've tried playing with the line:

```
searchResults = [filtroUsuario valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.usuario.nome"];
```

and got some interesting results, but not the one I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to use `@distinctUnionOfObjects.usuario`, so your results is an array of `user` objects (or some other objects with the keys that you require). Then in the table view cell setup you do:

```
id user = searchResults[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [user valueForKey:@"nome"];
cell.otherTextLabel.text = [user valueForKey:@"sobrenome"];
```